# angular UI bootstrap carousel slide issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using angular 1.3.0, angular animate and angular ui-bootstrap.

I am trying to create a carousel using code:

```
<carousel>
  <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides">
    <ul class="list studies live-studies md-study">
      some code goes here
    </ul><!-- /.list -->
  </slide>
</carousel>
```

**Issue description:**
If I press prev or next button to fast.Slide flash just like a flash of camera. Slide get hidden and come back after a while.

It looks like a ui break.

I was looking some thing similar https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/1273 but can't understand what to done.